# The inequality $(ae^{bx} - be^{ax} - (a -b)) > 0$

Tags: functions, inequality

I'm struggling to see why for $0<a<b$ it's true that for every $x\in \mathbb{R}, x>0$ :
$$(ae^{bx} - be^{ax} - (a -b)) > 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $f(x)=ae^{bx}-be^{ax}$ and note that $f(0)=a-b$. Next note that
$$
f'(x)=abe^{bx}-abe^{ax}=abe^{ax}(e^{(b-a)x}-1)
$$
which vanishes only for $x=0$. Can you finish?

The inequality holds for $x\ne0$, not only for $x>0$.

Comment: you're right, I wrote the question wrong, I corrected it

Answer (score 3):

We can use Jensen's Inequality:

Let $\displaystyle f(z)= e^{zx}$ and as $f(z) $ is convex, implies: $\ \displaystyle ae^{bx} - be^{ax} \geq (a-b) f \left ( \frac{ab-ba}{a-b}\right ) = (a-b) \ 
$

Therefore,

> $$\displaystyle  ae^{bx} - be^{ax} -  (a-b) \geq 0 .$$

Here, there is absolutely no restriction on $a,b$. And the equality holds when the condtion $a=b$ is satisfied.

Comment: Nice answer. A minor point is showing the case(s) for equality based on the question as posed by OP.

Comment: @JacobA oh ok,  Will Edit it. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Just wondering: $\frac{a}{a-b}$ and $-\frac{b}{a-b}$ play the role of the weights here as far as I understand, but the weights should be non-negative, or?

Comment: @Diger By the way, equivalently, you may use $\frac{b-a}{b}f(0) + \frac{a}{b}f(b) \ge f(a)$ which is $\frac{b-a}{b} + \frac{a}{b}\mathrm{e}^{bx} \ge \mathrm{e}^{ax}$.